# How to add @ApiImplicitParam as a doclet option using swagger-doclet?

Tags: java, maven, swagger, dropwizard

I have currently integrated with swagger-doclet to generate static docs for my dropwizard application. My application is a maven project.

I have added a request filter in my app that mandates a Client-ID header in the servlet request. If not present, it throws a 403.

Is there way that I can add this implicit header while generating the static api docs in swagger-doclet? Is there a doclet option available for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like having a dynamic behavior for static generation isn't going to be possible.  It sounds like the best approach would be to model a security requirement in your app, which should get picked up by the plugin.

Comment: Yeah I realized it. I patched the js in the assets to inject the headers that my app expects.